# JavaMail api usage in a web application

Tags: java, java-ee-6, jakarta-mail

I am developing a Java EE 6 web application, i want to add email notifcations to users who will subscribe in this web application.

the applications is pretty simple buts it needs to send users responses via email.

I learned that there is a JavaMail API available, should I use it ? or there is a better approach to do this ?

I am not asking on how to use it, i am asking wether its recommended or not, for safety and authenitaction measures, also performance ofcourse

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer has more to do with the organization in which you develop the app than the app itself.

If you're writing this for yourself or another organization, it's likely that you'll want a mail server to handle sending those emails.  You can have your app send the request to create the email, but the mail server will do what it was born to do and send the email.

Comment: so, i should use a mail server instead ?

Comment: It's not either/or.  Use JavaMail to process mail messages in a Java program.  JavaMail needs a mail server to talk to so you'll need one of those as well.  You can use your own, or you can use a service that provides a mail server, such as Gmail or your ISP.